# Can I pass the result of a method into an outputLink target attribute?

Tags: apex, visualforce, mobile, windows8

I have the following:

```
<apex:outputLink value="somePage" target="_parent">

</apex:outputLink>
```

Unfortunately, the target attribute [does not work on Windows8 devices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/ff462082(v=vs.105).aspx).

Any value other than _self causes the link to break.

So I think I need to check for Windows 8 and then pass the appropriate value into my target attribute.

Can I do somthing like this?

Controller:

```
public String isWindows8 { get; set; } 

public String setIsWindows8() {

    if(SOME USER AGENT CHECK FOR WINDOWS 8){
        isWindows8 =  '_self';
    }else{
        isWindows8 =  '_parent';
    }

    return isWindows8;
}
```

VF Page:

```
<apex:outputLink value="somePage" target="{!isWindows8}">

</apex:outputLink>
```

I need to have the target attribute in desktop as the link is embedded in the Opp layout and without the target attribute, it will not navigate to a new page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following in Apex to detect if the user is running Windows 8 (the value 'Windows NT 6.2' is taken from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ie/hh920767(v=vs.85).aspx)):

```
public Boolean isWindows8
{
    get
    {
        return ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders().get('USER-AGENT')
            .contains('Windows NT 6.2');
    }
}
```

Then make use of it in your Visualforce page as follows:

```
<apex:outputLink value="somePage" target="{!IF(isWindows8, '_self', '_parent'}">
```

Comment: Cheers Alex, much nicer approach than my first try! Much appreciated!